# StyleCop : Warning not suppressed

Tags: c#, build, warnings, stylecop

I am working on a project in which style cop rule set is already introduced.
Rule set contains rules which will suppress warnings from project.

*Even if rule set is already defined, warnings are displayed in Warning list tab.*

[image]

My question is what I am missing here? or how to suppress all warning which are mentioned in .`.DotSetting`.

Here is the code from `.DotSetting` file

```
<wpf:ResourceDictionary xml:space="preserve" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:ss="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:settings-storage-xaml" xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/Highlighting/InspectionSeverities/=ArrangeThisQualifier/@EntryIndexedValue">DO_NOT_SHOW</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/Highlighting/InspectionSeverities/=StyleCop_002ESA1101/@EntryIndexedValue">DO_NOT_SHOW</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/Highlighting/InspectionSeverities/=StyleCop_002ESA1126/@EntryIndexedValue">DO_NOT_SHOW</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/Highlighting/InspectionSeverities/=StyleCop_002ESA1200/@EntryIndexedValue">DO_NOT_SHOW</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/Highlighting/InspectionSeverities/=StyleCop_002ESA1623/@EntryIndexedValue">DO_NOT_SHOW</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/Highlighting/InspectionSeverities/=StyleCop_002ESA1633/@EntryIndexedValue">DO_NOT_SHOW</s:String>
    <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/Highlighting/InspectionSeverities/=StyleCop_002ESA1126/@EntryIndexedValue">DO_NOT_SHOW</s:String>
</wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```

Please correct me if I missed something or wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Settings.StyleCop file. You can configure it easily with [Stylecop plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChrisDahlberg.StyleCop) for VS.

Right click on the specific project -> StylecopSettings

[image]

You can choose then what rules you want to skip in the warnings tab

[image]

That generates a Settings.StyleCop file by Project.

Comment: Wow.. I tried it again checked each code from .dotSettings file. Unchecked required rules and now all warning related to codes which I specified get suppressed. Cheers, your solution works for me...