How to Suppress SA1633 in an External File Using StyleCop Analyzers with EditorConfig?
I'm using StyleCop analyzers with an EditorConfig in my C# project. I've suppressed the SA1633 rule by adding the following line to my EditorConfig:
dotnet_diagnostic.SA1633.severity = none
However, I'm still receiving the SA1633 error from a file that is not part of my solution:
C:\Users\**username**\.nuget\packages\community.visualstudio.toolkit.17\17.0.339\build\AssemblyInfo.cs
I suspect this is happening because the file is outside of my solution, and the EditorConfig settings only apply to files within the solution folder.
Is there a way to ensure the suppression applies globally, or another approach to handle this within the EditorConfig? Or to suppress any warning from external files?
Notes:

I can suppress the warning by adding <NoWarn>SA1633</NoWarn> in the project file, but that would require managing diagnostic severity in two places. I want to keep the management centralized in the EditorConfig.
I can use .ruleset file. But I prefer to use .EditorConfig file (To get warnings for code styles in build)


May be this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53726904/6299857

I'm not aware of a way to do this without using NoWarn or a .ruleset file.
